# Making divs go backwards in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's some example code

```
<div id="one">One</div><div id="two">Two</div><div id="three">Three</div>
```

And let's say the CSS is

```
div {float:left;}
```

Is there anyway to make the divs appear as Three, Two, One, besides something like `float:right`? JavaScript and jQuery not excluded.

Comment: Assuming you can't simply change the HTML order.... then absolute positioning would be the only way.

Comment: Well, you *could* use JavaScript/jQuery to move the elements around, but that's somewhat ugly.

Comment: Scripts really shouldn't be used to move elements around... it becomes a headache later. I think Scott has the best advice; just change the order. Well, what are you trying to achieve ultimately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually the exact example used on this [JQuery documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) for `$.makeArray()`:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);
arr.reverse();
$(arr).appendTo(document.body);
```